# Accessing the raw parameters of a Windows Animation Library

Tags: windows, animation

I am leveraging the Windows Animation Library. I want to be able to access the raw parameters that define the animations in the Windows Animation Library?

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can leverage the Windows.UI.Core.AnimationMetrics library to measure such things as StaggerDelay, DelayLimit, ZOrder and so on.

The ApplicationDescription class exposes a collection of individual animation effects that are performed on a specific target to make up a complete Windows opacity, scaling, or translation animation.

You can read more here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.animationmetrics.animationdescription.aspx